# bash alias to search for a string

Tags: bash, alias

I am adding an alias to search for a file for a string that leads to me a snippet.

```
alias snippets="find /oneDrive/Work/Snippets -type f -exec grep -Hi $1 '{}' + "
```

And calling as

```
snippets "target"
```

And getting error as

```
find: target: unknown primary or operator
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: 1. positional arguments like `$1` don't work in aliases. 2. even if `$1` worked, it would be expanded when the alias is defined (because it's within `"..."`), not when it's used. 3. use a function instead of an alias: `snippets(){ find /oneDrive/Work/Snippets -type f -exec grep -Hi "$1" {} +; }`

Comment: Everything said above, better to use a function. But no need for `find`, `grep` has recursive mode using `-r`.